# TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```html
  {% for cat in professions %}
    <a href="profession/{{ pro.id }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{% cat.title %}}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Это строчка, на которую ругается. Вроде всё верно. Что не так?)

Comment: Уберите проценты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы поставили слишком много процентов.

Код должен быть такой:

```html
...
  {% for cat in professions %}
    <a href="profession/{{ pro.id }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ cat.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Уберите лишние проценты здесь `{{% cat.title %}}`

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте объяснил, как именно надо изменить код.